TypedDict annotation for dict function param not taking effect?
This is my test snippet:
qxu@xqiang-mac-0:~/test$ cat test.py
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
from pprint import pformat
from typing import TypedDict

class MyDictWithCertainKeys(TypedDict):
    key_a: bool
    key_b: bool
    key_c: str

def set_to_target(target_values: MyDictWithCertainKeys):
    print(f"target values are: {pformat(target_values)}")

set_to_target({"foo": "bar"})

I was expecting the function would raise an exception complaining about target_values doesn't contain the required keys, when it is called. Yet it passed.
qxu@xqiang-mac-0:~/test$ ./test.py
target values are: {'foo': 'bar'}

The python version on my mac is 3.12.5.
